# jQuery click function not firing at smaller screen size, only larger?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a `click function` working on my hamburger icon when the screen size is at a phone screen size. The click function works when the screen size is greater than `800px's` but if it is anything less than that it doesn't fire. It seems to be something to do with the use of `position: absolute` on the hamburger icon as if you remove the position absolute and change it to `position: relative` or remove it all together it works as intended. I am using bootstraps media queries aswell. What am I doing wrong?

Demo of my code, (You will need to resize your browser to test): http://jsfiddle.net/nqLtvmd3/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="nice-blue-bg">
                    <div class="container">

                            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger mobile-nav-icon"></div>

                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="logo">
                                            TESTING                                     
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                                <nav>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li class="">
                                                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                                                            <a href="#">About Me</a>
                                                            <a href="#">Latest Work</a>
                                                            <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </nav>
                                            </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
```

css:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;

}

a:hover, a:focus { 
    text-decoration:  none;
    color: yellow;
}
/* Fix firefox issue with images not resizing whilst using bootstrap class */
.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}

.nice-blue-bg {


  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* W3C */

    width: 100%;
    height: 620px;
    position: relative;

}



.logo {
    font-family: Lato;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 80px;
}


nav {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li, nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: right;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


/* This is the css for the icon when the screen size is greater than 991px */
.mobile-nav-icon {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;  
}

@media (max-width: 991px) { 

/* This is the css for the icon when the screen size is less than 991px */
    .mobile-nav-icon {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .logo {
        text-align: center;
    }

    nav {
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: none;
    }

    nav li {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }

    .welcome {
        text-align: center;
    }

    nav li, nav a {
        margin-left: 0;
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    nav a {
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }

    nav a:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }


    .nice-blue-bg {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }



}
```

js:

```
$('.mobile-nav-icon').click(function() {
    alert('this is working');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to increase the element's `z-index`. Otherwise the sibling `.row` element will overlap it when the screen size is smaller. Increasing it to `1` will suffice given the fact that the sibling elements have a default `z-index` of `auto`, or in this case `0`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/utcykbdb/)

```
.mobile-nav-icon {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

It's also worth pointing out that you can avoid setting a `z-index` and place the icon element *after* the sibling elements in the DOM. In doing so, it will be placed on top.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgcgd33e/)

Comment: I am trying to position the hamburger icon using the values  e.g top: 10 etc. But it wont allow me to do it? Any ideas? I have put the hamburger icon right after the body tag and have given the body tag a position: relative. Updated jsfildde: http://jsfiddle.net/nqLtvmd3/4/